# How to fit train and validation data together

Tags: tensorflow, model-fitting

```
history = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    validation_generator,
    steps_per_epoch= 2403//32,
    epochs= 5,
)
```

This is the code , that I'm currently using and I'm getting the following error:
`ValueError: 'y' argument is not supported when using 'keras.utils.Sequence' as input.`
I've 2403 training images and 600 validation images , I'm using a batch size of 32 , pls guide me on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass your validation data as follows when your inputs are generated from the generator.

```
history = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    steps_per_epoch= 2403//32,
    epochs= 5,
)
```

Comment: Here steps_per_epoch = 2403//32  , but the validation images are only 600 , wouldn't this cause some redundant iterations?

Comment: normally, set: `step_per_epoch = len(train_generator) / batch_size` and `validation_steps = len(validation_generator) / batch_size`.